# ¿Como generar un programa conversor de Decimal a Xs3? c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, bucles

soy nuevo en esto, pero mi duda es la siguiente.

Tengo este código:

```
public long xs3(long a)
    {
        string cad = Convert.ToString(a);
        long suma=0;
        foreach (char c in cad)
        {
            suma=  long.Parse(c.ToString())+3;
            string binar = Convert.ToString(suma, 2);
            long i = 0;
            if (!Int64.TryParse(binar, out i))
            {
                i = -1;
            }
            return i;
        }
        return suma;
    }
```

Para sacar exceso 3 se tienen que sumar +3 cada uno de los números introducidos por separado. 
Ejemplo:

```
long n= "126"; //Ya sumados tendrían que dar "459"
```

Y después pasar cada numero a binario

```
//Tendría que dar 0100 0101 1001.
```

Mi duda es ... como sumo cada numero introducido en la cadena por separado, por que lo que hace mi código es solamente sumar el primer dato introducido y solo si es uno, si introduzco mas el programa me lo toma como si solo hubiera introducido uno.
Ejemplo:

```
En la salida de un solo numero introducido: 6 = 9 en binario ->1001
En la salida de dos números en adelante: 11 = 44 en binario debería ser 0100 0100
pero en pantalla solo aparece 0100 haciendo que se pierda un dato en el abismo existencial.
```

Así que mi duda es esa, como seguir sumando datos y que se sigan imprimiendo para que aparezcan todos los datos en lugar de mostrarme solo uno.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si un dígito es mayor que 6? ¿Se acarrea el resultado? Si es 181 ¿debería pasar a 413 o a 313?

Comment: Hay un *return* dentro del bucle, el bucle solo se ejecuta una vez... Deberías aprender a user un depurador, o seguir el funcionamiento de tu programa imprimiendo valores intermedios por consola.

Comment: Si es mayor a 6 sigue siendo el mismo procedimiento, ya que el resultado que de, debe pasar a BCD, por ejemplo un 9 daría un 12 y ese 12 pasaría a 1100

He quitado el return dentro del bucle, pero al ejecutar ahora solo me muestra el ultimo dato añadido, se que debo usar un arreglo, pero no se como implementarlo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Me respondo a mi mismo por si alguien llegar a hacer un conversor como este.

```
public string xs3(long a)
        {
            string cad = Convert.ToString(a);
            long suma=0;
            string BCD = "0000";
            string resul1 = null;
            string resul2 = null;

        foreach (char c in cad)
        {
            suma =  long.Parse(c.ToString())+3;
            string binar = Convert.ToString(suma, 2);
            long i = 0;
            if (!long.TryParse(binar, out i))
            {
                i = -1;
            }
            resul1 = i.ToString(BCD);
            resul2 += resul1.ToString() + " ";
        }
        return resul2;
    }
```

Logre hacerlo funcionar después de varios intentos.

Cambie el tipo de dato de `long` a `string`
Declare un "formato" de `BCD` ya que al convertirlo en números inferiores a 7 no se mostraba el 0 que tenia delante

Ejemplo: 
`4+3= 7 = 111` en lugar de `0111` como debería de ser, para eso es el formato.

Declare dos nuevos `strings` uno para que lo acomodaran conforme al formato, y el otro como un acumulativo de los resultados introducidos.

Lo demás es técnicamente lo mismo, solo difiere en los resul1 y 2.

Añado imagen de como quedo al final con el Xs-3 totalmente funcional.

[image: Añado una imagen de como el conversor funciono con las modificaciones.]